# jQuery validate date in IE not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, date

The date format in jQuery is 'dd/M/yyyy' (24/Apr/2012),

The code for this is:

```
jQuery('.dateofbirth').datepicker({ 
            dateFormat: 'dd/M/yy', 
            changeMonth: true, 
            changeYear: true,
            maxDate: new Date,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            minDate: '-100y'
        });

jQuery("#personDetailsForm").validate({
                rules: {
                        dateofdeath: {
                                required: true,
                                date: true
                        }
                }
        });
```

it works in Firefox and Chrome but does not work in IE. just cant seem to get it to work.

If I type 24/04/2012 in the date control (in IE) it validates fine but 24/Apr/2012 just doesnt work.

Any suggestions?